# Local volatility model for autocallable pricing

Tags: volatility, local

I am working on a pricer for an Autocallable product in Python. Coupons are accumulated at each observation and paid once the AC barrier is reached. At maturity, short down-and-in put.
I am trying to price it with local volatility model, but have some trouble to implement it. I have several questions :

- I guess I would like to transform implied volatilities to local volatilities with the Dupire formula, then price vanilla options and calibrate to reduce some error metric. But what would be the parameters to optimize ?
- How to price the bond part with autocall probabilities (and get those probabilities) ? should I weight several bonds with those probabilities ?

Does anyone has some code reference for such a model (language does not matter) that could help me ?

I am also open to other suggestions of model implementation for this product such as rough volatility, etc.

Comment: Hello did you find a solution?